# При каких обстоятельствах может пригодиться использование поля audience в jwt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, криптография, аутентификация, jwt

Пишу API для SPA с использованием ASP .NET Core WebAPI. Разбираюсь с возможностями и настройками jwt.

По умолчанию включена проверка audience.
Поискав значение этого параметра не понял зачем может возникнуть нужда его использовать. Обычно в примерах использования указывают url(вероятно клиентского приложения) или список из id клиентов или на название группы "web".
Если даже по особенному делать логику для разных аудиторий, почему не использовать роли? И как красиво делать разграничение этой логики не очень понятно.

Решил у себя убрать эту проверку, но зачем вообще по дефолту ставили проверку не важного параметра?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audience определяет что токен выдан именно для использования вашим приложением.

Предположим провайдер токенов - это какой-нибудь Windows Azure AD или Google. Вы отключиили проверку Audience.

Злоумышленник регистрирует в AD / Google свое приложение, заманивает на него пользователя.

Получает валидный токен с Audience = "левое приложение". И с этим токеном идет к вам в API.

И вы его пускаете (т.к. Audience не проверяется), и начинаете отдавать ему секретные данные пользователя, которые ваше приложение хранит, и позволяете производить действия от имени пользователя. Хотя пользователь на это согласия не давал.

А с валидацией - все ок, злоумышленника завернет при первом же запросе.

Comment: Вероятно я плохо понимаю процесс. 'Получает валидный токен с Audience = "левое приложение" ', но у пользователя если я убрал Audience при создании токена его вообще не будет и злоумышленник добавить туда свой Audience тоже не сможет из-за наличия подписи. Данная ситуация ясна, похитил токен - получил доступ к ресурсу пользователя. А можно подробнее процесс при наличии в токене Audience и валидации, как он должен проверяться?  Если я возьму и просто сравню значение которое я отдавал пользователю с значением которое мне пришло при запросе ресурса - злоумышленник аналогично получит доступ.

Comment: @AndreyMagnificent в примере из ответа токен создаете не вы, что в нем будет содержаться определяете не вы, а стронний сервис. Чтобы понять, что сторонний сервис выдал токен именно вашему приложению, а не какому то другому, вам надо проверять поле Audience токена самому у себя.

Comment: @AndreyMagnificent в схеме с JWT токен может выдаваться одним приложением, а проверяться - другим. Например, на SO можно входить через Google. Токен выдается гуглом, с audience="so". SO при этом доверяет только токенам, выданным Google для входа именно на SO. Если бы он доверял токенам с другим audience - то владельцы других сайтов, куда вы заходили через Google, могли бы использовать токены для работы на SO от вашего имени.